# Can't get the right data I send

Tags: android

My code is :

```
String str= (char)255 + (char)255 +"1" ;
byte[] sendbuf = str.getBytes();
outputPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendbuf,sendbuf.length,remoteIP,2280);

logSocket.send(outputPacket);
```

the result I get is **"0x35 0x31 0x30 0x31"**

but what I want is :**0xff 0xff 0x31**

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `str` is adding the two `char`s first, so it's basically this:

```
String str = (char)(255 + 255) + "1"; // 5101
```

What you want is (something like) this:

```
String str = (char) 255 + "" + (char) 255 + "1";
```

Or, using `String.format`:

```
String str = String.format("%c%c%d", 255, 255, 1);
```